# Trying to manually set the x-axis range for a date variable

Tags: r, date, datetime, ggplot2

I want to have the x-axis run from March until November although the dates only run between April and August.

Generate random date data and convert to data frame

```
date.data <- sample(seq(as.Date("2016-04-01"),as.Date("2016-08-  31"),by = "day"),50)

date.df <- as.data.frame(date.data)
```

generate ggplot histogram with default values for x-axis

```
ggplot(date.df,aes(date.data)) + geom_histogram()
```

Attempt to override the default values by writing a datebreaks vector and using a scale command.  The resulting histogram still only spans April through August.

```
datebreaks <- seq(as.Date("2016-03-01"),as.Date("2016-11-15"),by = "month")

ggplot(date.df,aes(date.data)) + geom_histogram() +   
  scale_x_date(breaks = datebreaks,labels=date_format("%b"))
```

How can I have the x-axis run from March until November?

aosmith made the useful suggestion to use xlim().  That works except the histogram has only the alternate months labeled on the axis. If I use scale_x_date to have each month labeled, that scale overrides the xlim(command)

```
mar <- as.Date("2016-03-01")
nov <- as.Date("2016-11-01")
ggplot(date.df,aes(date.data)) + geom_histogram() +   
 xlim(c(mar,nov))
```

Just what I am looking for except only alternate months appear as labels.

The addition of the scale command gets all months labeled but I lose the March to November span of the x-axis.

```
mar <- as.Date("2016-03-01")
nov <- as.Date("2016-11-01")
ggplot(date.df,aes(date.data)) + geom_histogram() +   
xlim(c(mar,nov)) + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b")
```

Anyone know a way to use xlim() and set the label formats (each month appearing as a label) at the same time?

Comment: Use `limits` within `scale_x_date`, not `xlim`, that way you can set the limits and the breaks at the same time.

Comment: `ggplot(date.df,aes(date.data)) + geom_histogram() +   
    scale_x_date(limits = c(mar, nov),
                 date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%b')` should work

Comment: Perfect! That solves my problem.  Thanks!